# Is it safe to update redux state outside the slice (in a reusable function)?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

Is it safe to update redux state outside the slice? So basically to have something like this in your code:

```
export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState: initState,
  reducers: {
    ...
    updateData(state, {payload}: PayloadAction<{ id: number; newData: TData }>) => {
      setData(state, payload)
    }
    ...
  }
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    ...
    .addMatcher(api.endpoints.getSomeData.matchFulfilled, (state, {meta, payload}) => {
      // some formatting of the data from the request
      ...
      setData(state, {id, newData})
    }
    ...
  }
})
// end of dataSlice

const setData = (
  state: WritableDraft<WritableDraft<IFiltersSlice>>,
  { id, newData }: { id: number; newData: TData }
) => {
  const idIndex = state.dataArr.findIndex((data) => data.id === id)

  if (idIndex !== -1) {
    if (newData.length === 2 && typeof newData[0] === "number" && typeof newData[1] === "number")
      state.dataArr[idIndex].value = newData

    state.dataArr[filterIndex].bounds = newData
  }
}
```

It looks a little sketchy to me, but I tried it, and it seems to work.

Another way to do it would be to return the state from `setData` and, in the slice, just return the result once more where the function is called. But, since redux toolkit uses Immer, I think this should also be fine?

Basically I found this in code, and I was wondering if it is bad (and if yes, why).
Also should we keep an eye out for this in the future?

I couldn't find anything related to this online (or in the docs). Maybe I just missed it?

Anyway any opinions are welcomed in the comments, and any [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) it up is deeply appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It does seem sketchy to me. I use the reducers array in Redux Toolkit’s createSlice for this kind of thing.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice

Comment: What reducer array? Redux toolkit slice `reducers` is an object, but it has nothing to do with my issue here.

Comment: I meant to say "map"